# Android Error: Device driver API match

Tags: android, eclipse

Should I be concerned with the error message "Device driver API match" and the following 3 lines (see code below)? What does it mean?  How to fix it?

I am simply running an app auto-generated by ADT Eclipse (new > Android Application Project) by following the Android Developer Training "My First App". The code has not been altered, and it is ran on Samsung Galaxy Note II (Android 4.3).

```
12-31 17:22:36.116: D/libEGL(10901): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-31 17:22:36.121: D/libEGL(10901): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-31 17:22:36.121: D/libEGL(10901): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-31 17:22:36.131: E/(10901): Device driver API match
12-31 17:22:36.131: E/(10901): Device driver API version: 23
12-31 17:22:36.131: E/(10901): User space API version: 23 
12-31 17:22:36.131: E/(10901): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9     21:05:57 KST 2013 
12-31 17:22:36.191: D/OpenGLRenderer(10901): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: I think this is just the ROM having a lot of debug symbols still in it upon shipping. Unless you flashed a new rom on the device, there is nothing your app code could do to have changed this

Comment: Thanks Greg. It seems likely since it only happens after Samsung updated the OS.

Comment: Yeah it's really annoying, you will see all sorts of debug stuff in all the View classes too that make calls to GLES but luckily it doesn't slow down the entire device.

Comment: Is there a way to separate/identify bugs that produced by the OS from those that I made?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have exactly the same problem. Have a brand new SGS3 but rooted it recently. Guess it means I rooted the wrong version???

Comment: @PatrickLee, you run your logging using a tag:
    Log.d("PatrickLee", "This is a log line");

And then when you tail the log with adb you can filter on just your tags: 
    adb logcat -s PatrickLee